# Share of happy marriages

Tags: experimental-psychology, sociology

I have googled quite alot to find any scientific statistics on any estimates of what share of all marriages consider themselves successfull. I understand that happiness is hard to measure, but is there at least somthing? What I've found was mostly recipes from/traits of successfull pairs, but this is not what I need.

Thanx

Comment: What you may be interested in is the amount of divorcing vs not-divorcing marriages.

Comment: No, I need any sort of life satisfaction surways.

Comment: Could you share some additional info on why you need other information. The more context you provide the more spot-on (and less guess-y) the answer will be